# VSCode - Is there a way to apply snippets to each line of a selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have a snippet. I want to select multiple lines - a set of relative paths to images that I have pasted in - and have the snippet be applied to each line separately. The snippet menu doesn't seem to have the same capabilities as Emmet (* treats each line separately)

Comment: try alt + left mouse click to enter multiple cursor anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- add multi cursors at each line: use `Ctrl+Alt+Down` or `Ctrl+Alt+Up`
- or any other method for multi cursor if you have few `Alt+Click` or a lot `Shift+Alt+Click`
- select the text of each line
- type the snippet prefix and select the snippet

this works if the snippet uses the variable `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}`